# Two way matching for Secret Santa game

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that pairs up men and women for a secret Santa type event. So I have 2 lists of boys and girls, and want to carry out 2 way matching, but at the moment I can only seem to figure out how to do 1 way matching.

Furthermore the problem I have is this... in the example below if Kedrick gets Annabel, then Annabel can't get Kedrick. Kedrick has to get someone else from the list.

My current implementation is as follows, how can I extend its functionality to meet the abovementioned requirements?

```
boys = ['Kedrick','Jonathan','Tim','Philip','John','Quincy'];
girls  = ['Annabel','Janet','Jocelyn','Pamela','Priscilla','Viviana'];

matches = []

for i in boys:
    rand - randint(0, len(girls-1)
    fullname = "{} matched with {}".format(i, girls(rand)
    del girls(rand)
    matches.append(fullname)

print matches
```

Comment: One small tip. Just [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) one of the lists and map by index. It works out easier

Comment: How Kedrick and Tim are connected? or is it just typo?

Comment: @Lafexlos there is no connection between them both

Comment: Is this your actual code? Among other issues, I would expect `del girls(rand)` to crash with `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`.

Comment: @Kevin from paired programming session I had with a friend, I am learning python at the moment: http://imgur.com/c6OMS3s

Comment: From your image itself `girls` **`[`** `rand` **`]`**

Comment: Ok, well, go ahead and transcribe that image into text and edit it into your post. Debugging code is much easier when you can copy/paste/run it.

Comment: Agree with kevin. Also, some syntax issues - I think you mean rand =, not rand -, plus you need a closing paren at the end of that line. You also need a closing paren on format. As written, does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could probably be done with fewer loops and a lot less code but here is my solution! Created 2 dict's to store names and their targets (dict's could be combined or done at the same time to cut down on memory issues, but with a program this size I don't think you would ever run into this issue!

```
boys = ['Kedrick','Jonathan','Tim','Philip','John','Quincy'];
girls  = ['Annabel','Janet','Jocelyn','Pamela','Priscilla','Viviana'];

matchesBoys = {i:{'to':''} for i in boys}
matchesGirls = {i:{'to':''} for i in girls}

for name in boys:
    giveTo = girls[random.randint(0, len(girls)-1)]
    girls.remove(giveTo)
    matchesBoys[name]['to']=giveTo

for name in matchesGirls:
    giveTo = boys[random.randint(0, len(boys)-1)]
    boys.remove(giveTo)
    matchesGirls[name]['to']=giveTo

del boys, girls
for i in matchesBoys:
    print "%s matched with %s"%(i, matchesBoys[i]['to'])
for i in matchesGirls:
    print '%s matched with %s'%(i, matchesGirls[i]['to'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle both lists and put them in a ring, with every other element being from the first or second list. Each person gives a gift to the one on their right. Something similar to a list like this:

```
[Girl, Boy, Girl, Boy, ..., Boy]
```

The last element gives a gift to the first.

It works under the assumption that both lists have the same amount of elements and that there are at least four elements in total, otherwise the problem is unsolvable.

This gives one solution that fulfills your constraints. The general solution to the problem is to find a directed [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) between the sets where each vertex have exactly two edges, one incoming and one outgoing. Perhaps the solution to that problem also always creates a ring?

Comment: I'm almost certain that my last remark is true but I leave it as an exercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation that creates a circle with alternate boy and girl. See @Emil Vickstom's answer for an explanation of the idea.

```
from random import shuffle
boys = ['Kedrick','Jonathan','Tim','Philip','John','Quincy'];
girls  = ['Annabel','Janet','Jocelyn','Pamela','Priscilla','Viviana'];

shuffle(boys)
shuffle(girls)
circle = [person for pair in zip(boys, girls) for person in pair]
print(' -> '.join(circle + circle[:1]))
```

Output:

> Tim -> Priscilla -> Quincy -> Annabel -> John -> Janet -> Kedrick ->
>   Jocelyn -> Philip -> Pamela -> Jonathan -> Viviana -> Tim